# Would it be possible, from the earth’s creation or during its various geomorphological changes, for all the following hypotheses to be probable?

Tags: geophysics, oceanography, earth-history, satellites, tides

I’m designing a fictional world setting for a game, and I would like to know whether it has a relative coherence based on science. (Don’t mind if it is an almost improbable scenario).

Would it be possible, from the earth’s creation or during its various geomorphological changes, for all the following hypotheses to be probable?

1. Earth has multiple natural satellites which create new natural phenomena (ex. extreme tides and tidal currents)
2. Earth temperature is higher enough to melt the ice so that humans can sail through the north and south pole, but also low enough for people to survive.

My thoughts: I was thinking maybe multiple asteroids colliding and some of them (big enough) entered the earth’s orbit and became natural satellites, while others crashed into the earth’s surface to reshape the landscape etc.
Alternatively, if there could be a whole different planet similar to earth which had multiple moons since it's creation.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the question is easy to answer - given that the Arctic has been ice free in relatively recent geological history, e.g. in the Mesozoic, and it is expected to be ice free in summer within a few decades as a result of global warming, positing a habitable planet where polar oceans are navigable, at least in summer seems fairly safe.